# Iterate hashmap's mongodb result in Freemarker

Tags: java, mongodb, freemarker

I am new at java and mongodb, and i dont see how to solve this, i have a collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "20minutos",
    "active" : true,
    "group" : "20 Minutos",
    "domains" : [
            "20minutos.com",
            "20minutos.es",
            "20minutos.tv"
    ]
```

}

java code:

```
get("/pages/:page", (request, response) -> {
        String page = request.params(":page");
        if(page.equals("forms")){
            UserDAO userDao = new UserDAO(Connection.getInstance().getDataStore());
            HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            map.put("users", userDao.AllUsers());
            return new ModelAndView(map, page+".ftl");
        }else{
            return new ModelAndView(null, page+".ftl");
        }
    }, new FreeMarkerEngine());
```

my AllUsers() function

```
public List<User> AllUsers() throws Exception{      
    return this.find().asList();
}
```

the pojo clas, the domains

```
public List<String> getDomains() {
    return domains;
}
```

and the freemarker code

```
<#list users as data>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>${data._id}</td>
    <td>${data.active?string('yes', 'no')}</td>
    <td>${data.group}</td>
    <#assign x = ''>
    <#assign keys = data?keys>
    <#list keys as key>
      <#assign x = x+','+key>
    </#list>
    <td>${x}</td>
</tr>
```

the problem is that i cant acces the values of Domains

i hope u someone can help me

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list user domains you can use [join](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_join):

```
<td>${data.domains?join(",")}</td>
```

Comment: i get this error "The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> data.domains" but the list isn't null because when i go step by step i see all the values, and i dont know why i am getting this error

Comment: it results that i did have one user whit a null domains, that was the error, when i put a domain in that one and use the "${data.domains?join(",")}" it works, thank you rostanek